# How to extract part of the string which comes after given substring?

Tags: ruby

For example I have url string like:

```
https://abc.s3-something.amazonaws.com/subfolder/1234/5.html?X-Amz-Credential=abcd12bhhh34-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=2016&X-Amz-Expires=3&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=abcd34hhhhbfbbf888ksdskj
```

From this string I need to extract number 1234 which comes after subfolder/. I tried with gsub but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is `subfolder` always the same? For that matter, is the domain name always the same?

Comment: I suggest: 1) you reduce the length of your string. Perhaps end it before `"-Amz-Credential"`. The question isn't changed and readers don't have to scroll horizontally to read the string. 2) assign a variable to the string (e.g., `str = "http..."`) so readers don't have to do that. They can just refer to the variable. 3) answer @Jordan's question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose your url is saved in a variable called `url`.
Then the following should return `1234`

```
url.match(/subfolder\/(\d*)/)[1]
```

Explanation:

```
url.match(/     # call the match function which takes a regex
  subfolder\/   # search for the first appearance of the string 'subfolder/'
                # note: we must escape the `/` so we don't end the regex early
  (\d*)         # match any number of digits in a capture group,
/)[1]           # close the regex and return the first capture group
```

Comment: In this case I would use \d+ to make sure there is at least one digit in the captured group (the URL would not make sense with two consecutive "/" characters

Answer (score 1):

```
url = 'http://abc/xyz'

index= url.index('/abc/')
url[index+5..length_of_string_you_want_to_extract]
```

Hope, that helps!

Comment: abc is dummy string after which you want some number, and the length(3) will change accordingly,  in your case, it will be 6

Answer (score 1):

lwassink has the right idea, but it can be done more simply. If `subfolder` is always the same:

```
url = "https://abc.s3-something.amazonaws.com/subfolder/1234/5.html?X-Amz-Credential=abcd12bhhh34-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=2016&X-Amz-Expires=3&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=abcd34hhhhbfbbf888ksdskj"

url[/subfolder\/\K\d+/]
# => "1234"
```

The `\K` discards the matched text up to that point, so only `"1234"` is returned.

If you want to get the number after *any* subfolder, and the domain name is always the same, you might do this instead:

```
url[%r{amazonaws\.com/[^/]+/\K\d+}]
# => "1234"
```

Comment: I've fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1):

```
s.split('/')[4]
```

Add a `.to_i` at the end if you like.

*Or,* to key it on a substring like you asked for...

```
a = s.split '/'
a[a.find_index('subfolder') + 1]
```

*Or,* to do it as a one-liner I suppose you could:

```
s.split('/').tap { |a| @i = 1 + a.find_index('subfolder')}[@i]
```

*Or,* since I am a damaged individual, I would actually write that:

```
s.split('/').tap { |a| @i = 1 + (a.find_index 'subfolder')}[@i]
```